# Android tabbar being rendered over the actionbar not below in devices below 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I am using `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` in my applications and it works great except for one detail

On devices pre `4.4.2` (I tested on 4.0, 4.1, 4.2 and 2.3)

`Kitkat` works fine but the rest doesn't

**`Kitkat`** and **Pre-`Kitkat`**:

[image: Kitkat]  [image: Pre Kitkat]

```
package com.example.testtabbar;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a {@link FragmentPagerAdapter}
     * derivative, which will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this
     * becomes too memory intensive, it may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter    mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager               mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(new Button(this));
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(final Context context, final FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public PlaceholderFragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER  = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabReselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.TabListener#onTabUnselected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction)
     */
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

EDIT: When using a custom view and a tab navigation, the tab navigation is on top in older devices, How can I make the action bar be rendered above the tab strip ?

The code above demonstrates the problem in 1 class, the button signifies a custom layout

Create 2 emulators 1 4.4 and the other is 2.3, when you run on both you will observe the problem.
[image]

Edit:

After trying the transparent icon here is the result:
P.S. the white on the left is the action bar bg, but the white in the middle is me removing some text from the screenshot to protect the identity of the application
[image: trans icon]

I need the icon on the left to be touching the left edge, so next will test ActionBarSherlock

Comment: You should take some time to edit your post and remove all of the unnecessary code. I removed some, but you've posted hundreds of lines and only a few are related to the `ActionBar`.

Comment: Would you please post a code with no external custom classes, or would please post a simple program which only has the problem because i got some classes and resources which are not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ViewPager` with `TabStrip` you can check it out in [this project](https://github.com/Shereef/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

Comment: Is that a kind of a joke? The one who is asking question has a Git repository, which contains the ViewPager with TapStrip.....????!!!!

Comment: @YuDroid She works with me at the same company, when she saw the question she told me verbally I implemented it, then I answered my self, and thought, why did I do that, I should let her take credit and I deleted my answer and let her type it in, Long story short, we aren't cheating!, but have it your way ;)

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue with support Library

so you have 2 solutions:

1- Use ActionBar Sherlock 
[ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

OR

2-Set Display Home Icon, in the below code i added blank home icon but you can replace it with
anything else

```
    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(new Button(this));
    //Hide Home Icon (as default)
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    //Hide Title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //if android < 19 4.4 
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19)
    {
        //display Home icon
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        //Set Blank Icon 
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.blank);
    }
```

But i prefer use ActionBar Sherlock.

Comment: I tried setting the home icon yesterday but it makes it impossible to have a custom icon for the side bar (not the triple line, we have something else that needs to be touching the left edge of the screen :( ), I will try the action bar sherlock and report back on sunday but,  I don't like using custom libraries when there is a Google solution, but if it works it works :):), Thanks ya H, will report on sunday isA

Answer (score 1):

In the OnCreate method update the line

`foractionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);`

and add new display option

`actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM| ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);`

this will view make the tabs under the action bar and will show the home icon. then you can update the home icon with a blank icon if you don't want it

You can use `actionBar.setIcon(yourImage);` where yourImage is a transparent png or a picture with 1*1 px resolution or an image you want to use to ovveride the **Home Icon**, this will change the **Home Icon** and keep the **Actionbar** above the **TabBar**

**Override the Home Screen Icon**

Or you can Set the icon you want as your home icon and then overrides `onMenuItemSelected`

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:


      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "home pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;

    }

    return true;
}
```

This will change the icon and put you action on its click and it will be at the most left side of the screen but there will be a small arrow ^_^ which means that this button opens a menu.

Comment: you can add `actionBar.setIcon(yourImage);` where **yourImage** is a transparent png or a picture with 1*1 px resolution, this will remove the home icon and keep the **actionbar** above the **TabBar**

Comment: I need to have an image touching the left edge of the screen, it won't work that way :(, but I will test it again today isA

Comment: You can override the home icon with a pixel by pixel icon and in your custom layout put the icon you want with your prefered action

Comment: Doesn't work ya @3amoura check my question the part after "After trying the transparent icon here is the result:"

Comment: @Shereef check my update after **Override the Home Screen Icon**